# ¿Cómo ingresar el id del usuario logueado en Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una tabla `reservas` que contiene un campo `created_by`, donde quiero registrar el usuario que efectuó la reserva, y no sé cómo o dónde hacer eso.

Tengo un archivo `SaveReservaRequest.php` y en la `function rules()`, he puesto lo siguiente:

```
'created_by' => Auth::id(),
```

Me da el siguiente error al pulsar el botón guardar, para insertar un nuevo registro.

> ```
> "array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, int given"
> ```

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto? Estoy utilizando Laravel 5.8.

Comment: Las clases que extienden de FormRequest, son para validar los datos que llegan en el request. Para "registrar el usuario que efectuó la reserva" debes hacerlo cuando insertas la reserva en la base de datos, en la función `store` de un controlador, por ejemplo

Comment: Gracias por la repuesta, Falto el ejemplo,
Tengo esto en la function store
public function store(Reserva $reserva, SaveReservaRequest $request)
     {
        Reserva::create( $request->validated() );
        $reserva->'created_by' = Auth::id();
        return redirect()->route('reservas.show', $reserva)->with('notification', 'Reserva ingresada exitosamente.');
     }
y da el siguiente error
"array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, int given"

Answer (score 1):

Parece que el validate del request te esta retornando un entero, revisa como se evalua la funcion o introduce en el create

```
$request->all();
```

Intenta usar el auth de esta forma

```
Auth::user()->id;
```